# Count matchings of the complement of a circuit

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have the need to find a way to count the total amount of [matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) of the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of a circuit.

I know I should use the [matching polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_polynomial) but I have no clue how to. The polynomial give me a way to count the matchings of a given graph but I can't understand how to do it. I've found specific formulas for notable graphs like circuits, chains and so on but the complement of a circuit is not included.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have two questions. 1: When you say matchings, do you mean any matchings, or maximum matchings? 2: In the complement of the circuit question, is the original graph made up entirely of the circuit (for example, might there be other nodes which just have degree 0)?

Comment: 1) Any matching. Maximum matchings would be easier.
2) Yeah, only the circuit and the complement is made of the diagonals of the  polygon formed by the circuit.

Comment: Here's a vague idea, which may or may not actually work. Start with the matching polynomial for $K_{n}$. For each coefficient (other than the constant 1), figure out what proportion of those matchings are still valid for the complement of $C_{n}$. It feels like, by the symmetry of $K_{n}$, that might only depend on the relative number of edges in $C_{n}$ and $K_{n}$. I'm not convinced that "might" statement is actually true, though....